# Sitecore CDP update products quantity with ADD, CONFIRM, CHECKOUT events

Tags: cdp

On most ecommerce websites, the user has the ability to change the number of products at the last step of the order.

**Question**: How to update quantity of order items by using ADD, CONFIRM, CHECKOUT workflow?

***Example***:

1. User add 1 product to order *(send ADD event with `"quantity": 1` )*:[image]
2. User changes product quantity to 5 *(before checkout)*:

[image]

3. Is expected that the `quantity` value can be changed in CONFIRM event, but it does not support `quantity` parameter, it only has `product.item_id` parameter *(that is useful if user removes some items from cart)*.

If we don`t update quantity, and send CONFIRM + CHECHOUT events after step.2 we will get 1 item in order instead of 5:
[image]

***Solutions that I know***:

- send additional ADD event with updated `quantity` field (but then there is no point in the original/first ADD event, and it is not clear when to trigger it to avoid many duplicates in CDP);
- use ORDER_CHECKOUT event (but then it makes no sense at all in the chain of ADD, CONFIRM, CHECKOUT events).

What is the best pratice to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can send [CLEAR_CART](https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-a-clear-cart-event-to-sitecore-cdp.html) and ORDER_CHECKOUT on any change in quantity, to avoid duplication. A normal flow would follow in case of no change.